# Listen when button pressed

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I've read about the on-click() but with is not wath i'm looking for. 
I need to access to the dom from a function and see if the button is pressed. I heard about ElementRef but could not figure out how to use it. I also saw that some class that i use like the marker on google map use addEventListener.

is this accurate code in typescript ? :

```
cursorDom.addEventListener("change", event => {
  console.log("change");
  if(document.getElementById('cursor').style.visibility=='visible'){
    console.log("visible");
  }else{
    console.log("invisible");
  }
});
```

**Edit:**

I've pass all day long to understand wath is the equivalent to addEventListener (renderer, elementRef, Viewchild...) it gets fuzier and fuzier. All i want to do is an eventListener that check if the div is visible are not with a todo function in it. The closest thing i found is this :

```
this.renderer.listen(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'click', () => { /* callback */ });
```

But didn't managed to work this out.

Let's say that i have a function were i have all my init, my Googlemarker gets created in it i want to set a listener to a div and listen if it is visible are not, and in function of that set the markers to visible or invisible.

**Edit 2 :**

Test on a blank page.

html:

```
<div id="cursor" #cursor [style.display]="isVisible ? 'inline' : 'none'"></div>
```

typescript:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';


@Component({
 selector: 'page-signup',
 templateUrl: 'signup.html'
})

export class SignupPage {
   @ViewChild('cursor') myDiv;
   constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, renderer: Renderer) {
       renderer.listen(this.myDiv, 'change', event => console.log(event));
}

 ionViewDidLoad() {
   console.log('Hello Signup Page');
 }
}
```

Error:

```
 Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **ViewChild** decorator to get any element that you want:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
   <div #myDiv>Div</div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  @ViewChild('myDiv') myDiv;


  ngAfterContentInit() {
    // This is the native element, do whatever you want
    console.log(this.myDiv.nativeElement)
  }  

}
```

Comment: Sorry i have tested this but can't see how it can replace an eventListener. I've pass all day long to understand wath is the equivalent to addEventListener (renderer, elementRef, Viewchild...) it gets fuzier and fuzier. All i want to do is an eventListener that check if the div is visible are not with a todo function in it.

Comment: Try to edit your question and explain better, because we don't understand really what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you need to add an event listener and a callback there is a `HostListener` module:

```
@HostListener('window:click', ['$event'])
callback(event) {}
```

Comment: How can i taget a div and see if it was visible or not with hostlistener ? I looked at some exemple and i can't still figure out how to target the element with an id : https://christianliebel.com/2016/05/angular-2-a-simple-click-outside-directive/

Comment: Ok. I understand. Hostlistener us not appropriate here. You probably need to use ViewChild or component property binded to target element [hidden]